# Magento admin login and logout issue

Tags: magento-1.8

when I tried to login into Magento admin it's show me error **Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.** and I know I am entering correct username and password. when I tried second time to login with same user name and password it's allow me to login successfully.

after 2 try finally I login to my Magento admin panel but after that when I click on logout it's refresh page and redirect me to dashboard.it's not logout from Magento admin panel.

any idea??

**Update**

now if I try to login in admin it's doesn't show any error it just refresh and url is changed.

for ex : 
my admin url is : example.com/admin
username : admin
password : admin@123

now if I try to login using this details page is refresh and my url is change from **example.com/admin** to **example.com/admin/index/index/key/95fdcbe3f6af413384d42ea557a7b4e7/**

Answer (score 1):

At Admin->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management set the "Cookie Path" to "/" and Cookie Domain: .site.com ,clear the browser cache and try again.
IF you can't login into the admin area, you can check it directly via mysql:

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%cookie_domain%';`

You can change the value in mysql directly as well. Don't forget to clear the cache afterwards.

Comment: in which table magento store **Cookie Path** and **Cookie Domain** becuase after use your solution I am not able to login into admin.

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Its look like your browser cache problem, did you try to clear your browser cache ? Please clear your browser cache or try to login with another browser.

Comment: I am trying to login in private browser.

Comment: Interesting, maybe that link will be helpful check Steve Robbins ansver 9 step solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036384/magento-admin-login-kicks-me-out-back-to-the-admin-login

Comment: check my updated question.